# PaymentActivity.EXTRA_SKIP_CREDIT_CARD can not be resolved

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am integrating Paypal SDk first time in my app and I want to hide  buy with credit card option from my application .I found that I can set `intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_SKIP_CREDIT_CARD, true);`

But when I am doing so it says PaymentActivity.EXTRA_SKIP_CREDIT_CARD can not be resolved .I have used demo app from github for integrating paypal into android .

Here is the [link](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK) .Please tell me how to resolve this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This extra has changed in 2.0+.  Please look at the [PayPalConfiguration javadocs](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-Android-SDK/com/paypal/android/sdk/payments/PayPalConfiguration.html).  Sorry for any lags in doc updates!

Comment: Thank you so much .Really helped however I wanted to use that functionality in my app but cardio scanner is not scanning card. Can you guide me how to use card.io lib in android app

Comment: Glad to hear it!  For a new question about card.io not working, I'd suggest you open a new question with more details about the problem you're facing.

Comment: I thought I could do it this way: intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,new PayPalConfiguration().acceptCreditCards(false)); but it doesn't disable the button?

Answer (score -1):

For example like this:

```
PayPalConfiguration() object = new PayPalConfiguration();
object = object.acceptCreditCards(false);
```

and then give object on the intent like this:

```
intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, object);
```